# Active MQ concurrency for different source systems and single consumer

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I have this problem that in my queue there are messages from different source systems.

For example: in the first message I have source system name as: 'X' and in the second one, the source system name is: 'Y'.

Currently I have a JMS listener with concurrency level set as 1. So all messages are getting processed one by one as expected, but now I want to process messages concurrently such that if messages are from the same source system then only one message should be processed for that source system at a time and if there are messages for different source systems they must be executed in parallel.

Source system are getting created dynamically, that's why I can't have separate queue and consumer for each source system.

It would be great if someone push me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is around maintaining ordered delivery for messages originating from a given source, but to be able to process messages from different sources in parallel.

You can do this using [message groups](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-0.30/cpp-broker/book/Using-message-groups.html).

> The broker allows messaging applications to classify a set of related
>   messages as belonging to a group. This allows a message producer to
>   indicate to the consumer that a group of messages should be considered
>   a single logical operation with respect to the application.

To make this work, have the producer systems set the JMSXGroupID header to the producer system name:

```
Mesasge message = session.createTextMessage("<message />");
message.setStringProperty("JMSXGroupID", "SourceSystem1Name");
```

Then the broker will enforce consumption ordering among messages belonging to that group.

**Addendum**

> There might be N numbers of source systems as they are created
>   dynamically and there is a producer which puts all the messages from
>   these N source systems into the queue

So the message producer can set the JMSXGroupID header to the name of the source system.

> The problem I'm facing is If the message for one source system is
>   getting processed, other source system messages have to wait till the
>   completion of processing of that message

So once the group header is set as described, the broker will ensure that it only releases messages for a given source system to the consumer sequentially. It does this by forcing the consumer to send an acknowledgement that a previous message has been processed, before releasing the next message in the group.

So by setting concurrency to some appropriate value, the consumer can process messages from different source systems in parallel but will be forced to sequentially process messages from any given source system, which is the behaviour you require.

Comment: By setting the JMSXGroupID, you will not be 100% sure the source X will be treated by the consumer which process messages sequentially (concurrent=1). And if that consumer gets down it is the other one who will treat all messages. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @ruffp my assumption is that the OP is only concerned with ordered delivery. I don't think he cares about group affinity switching from one consumer to another, only that messages from a given source system are processed in order. By using message groups the broker will guarantee messages within the group are delivered in order.

Comment: @tom_redfern the sentence `and if there are messages for different source systems they must be executed in parallel` make me think all others system must be treated in parallel. With the group, every system instances would be treated sequentially and globally seeing, all systems would be treated in parallel (E.g: all X goes to consumer1, all Y to consumer2 and all Z to consumer3).

Comment: Let me be more clear, There might be N numbers of source systems as they are created dynamically and there is a producer which puts all the messages from these N source systems into the queue which has only one consumer. The problem I'm facing is If the message for one source system is getting processed, other source system  messages have to wait till the completion of processing of that message.

Answer (score 0):

Because the consumer is declared on the consumer side, you cannot dynamically (at my knowledge) change it according to another variable.

The solution I would suggest is to use selectors and use two consumer connections like the following:

Consumer endpoint for parallel processing (5 in this case) will looks like:

```
activemq:queue:MY_QUEUE_UNIQUE?concurrentConsumers=5&selector=MySourceHeader<>'X'
```

Consumer endpoint for sequencial processing will looks like:

```
activemq:queue:MY_QUEUE_UNIQUE?concurrentConsumers=1&selector=MySourceHeader='X'
```

It would be good as well to define a fetch size of one for the queue (even I am not sure it is mandatory).